# Springboot deploy fails in wildfly 17 after update to jdk 11

Tags: spring-boot, openjdk-11, wildfly-17

I have some apps built with spring boot 2.1.2 and running in wildfly 10 with jdk 8, so far every thing ok... but after update the apps do springboot 2.2.1, wildfly 17 and open jdk 11 everything "exploded". If it happened with someone please could post the solution?
below a part of deploy log:

```
 15:59:56,319 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'literalTranslatedService' defined in VFS resource ["/content/fluig-i18n-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/fluig-i18n-4.0.1.jar/com/fluig/core/i18n/service/LiteralTranslatedService.class"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'literalTranslatedRepository' defined in VFS resource ["/content/fluig-i18n-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/fluig-i18n-4.0.1.jar/com/fluig/core/i18n/service/repository/LiteralTranslatedRepository.class"]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'literalTranslatedRepository' defined in VFS resource ["/content/fluig-i18n-war.war/WEB-INF/lib/fluig-i18n-4.0.1.jar/com/fluig/core/i18n/service/repository/LiteralTranslatedRepository.class"]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
 Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:214)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:471)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:350)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1807)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    ... 51 more
 Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Unable to instantiate proxy using Objenesis, and regular proxy instantiation via default constructor fails as well; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:81)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:205)
    ... 58 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//org.springframework.aop.framework.ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.createProxyClassAndInstance(ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.java:78)
    ... 59 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//com.fluig.data.jpa.dao.AbstractRepository.<init>(AbstractRepository.java:23)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//com.fluig.core.i18n.service.repository.LiteralTranslatedRepository.<init>(LiteralTranslatedRepository.java:16)
    at deployment.fluig-i18n-war.war//com.fluig.core.i18n.service.repository.LiteralTranslatedRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5bf475b1.<init>(<generated>)
    ... 64 more
```

any suggestion?

Comment: I encountered the same low-level cause: "class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType". The solution was to add the module jdk.unsupported to our JRE that we were building with jlink. Our application worked fine with the full JDK installed, but our minimal JRE we were building did not have that module.